# Setting up cuda template project from NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK for GTK+

Tags: templates, makefile, gtk, cuda, nvidia

I'm developing CUDA with Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 11.10. To set up a new CUDA project, i use the template project from the NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK and customize the makefile. For gui development i'm using gtk+ in a normal C file. But every time building the project, i get */usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.* So my question is: How can i set up the gcc compiler for gtk+ development in the makefile given by nvidia?

Comment: The best advice I can give about the SDK makefile is "just don't use it". It is terribly complex, a bit buggy, and not intended for use outside of the SDK code examples.

Comment: Seconded.  It's something we'll be moving away from ourselves in future versions of the CUDA code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this question from the unanswered list...  When starting a new project in CUDA, I recommend using a simple makefile, not the CUDA SDK's "common.mk" approach.

NVIDIA will be simplifying the SDK in the future, and hopefully provide a simple template makefile.

Comment: Okay thx, i wrote a bashscript with nvcc and gcc commands. Now it works.